# Pandas remove rows without common values in multilevel categorical dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Say I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns:

`col1` can be `P` or `Q`

`col2` can be `X` or `Y`

`col2` can be `A`, `B`, `C` or `D`

input:

```
   col1 col2 col3
0     P    X    B
1     P    X    D
2     P    Y    A
3     P    Y    B
4     P    Y    D
5     Q    X    A
6     Q    X    B
7     Q    X    C
8     Q    X    D
9     Q    Y    A
10    Q    Y    C
```

I would like to output a dataframe with rows removed such that for each catagory in `col1`, the values in `col3` are equal across the categories in `col2`.

output:

```
   col1 col2 col3
0     P    X    B
1     P    X    D
3     P    Y    B
4     P    Y    D
5     Q    X    A
7     Q    X    C
9     Q    Y    A
10    Q    Y    C
```

I may be overcomplicating things... but initially thinking along the lines of using `groupby` and somehow applying set intersections but struggling with implementation.

```
>>> df.groupby(["col1", "col2"])["col3"].unique()
col1  col2
P     X             [B, D]
      Y          [A, B, D]
Q     X       [A, B, C, D]
      Y             [A, C]
```

Another approach I have tried is to make an aggregated "truth table" using `pd.crosstab`

```
>>> x = pd.crosstab([df.col1, df.col2], df.col3)
>>> (x>0).groupby(level=0).agg(all)
col3      A      B      C      D
col1
P     False   True  False   True
Q      True  False   True  False
```

Comment: For me the condition for removing rows is not clear. Could you elaborate on why the row "2     P    Y    A" for example falls under the conditon?

Comment: I was struggling to clearly describe it in words… I think it might be best explained by looking at the groupby example I showed. Essentially what I want is, for each entry in col1, the lists in col2 to be identical. If look at row P, we have one list for X and one for Y. The set intersection between those lists is {B, C}, therefore the A item should be discarded.

Comment: typo: the set intersection is {B, D}, not {B, C}

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind this solution is that we leave only the rows where **the number of {col1_value, col3_value} pairs is greater than 1**.

So, if the number of some {col1_value, col3_value} pair is equal to 1 then it means that there's no intersection by "col3" between {col1_value, col2_value} groups because only 1 row with either "X" or "Y" exists for this certain {col1_value, col3_value} pair.

Otherwise, if the number of some {col1_value, col3_value} pair is greater than 1 then it means either

1. some intersection by "col3" between {col1_value, col2_value} groups exists because we have both "X" and "Y" for the pair.
2. or there are duplicates with the same "X" or "Y" values in col2 for the {col1_value, col3_value} pair. 
   **I assume that this case with duplicates is impossible because of the character of the data.** 
   **If such duplicates are possible then please inform me and the solution will be developed accordingly.**

> Solution

```
df.groupby(["col3", "col1"]).filter(lambda g: len(g) > 1)
```

> Result

```
  col1 col2 col3
0     P    X    B
1     P    X    D
3     P    Y    B
4     P    Y    D
5     Q    X    A
7     Q    X    C
9     Q    Y    A
10    Q    Y    C
```